# Careers 2.0 - Revoke Invitations

Tags: support, status-declined, jobs, invitation

How do I revoke the 3 Careers invitations I wasted on some former co-workers who are not interested in having a Careers 2.0 profile?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Right now there's no way to revoke an invitation once it's sent, but I figure since you asked so nicely I'll give some to make up for it.

Comment: Thanks!  I saw the notification - I have a few I could give out but I also was asking because it might be a nice feature to ask those that didn't use it if they would bounce it back to you / me so we could re-assign it - like a real nice decline feature.

Comment: I'll certainly add that feature to the wish list.

Comment: Any update on this? I have one I'd like to revoke as well.